# Issue Creating Automated Deployment with Guard

Tags: ruby, jekyll, guard

I am working to automate the deployment of my Jekyll site. This what the finished product will be:

1. I push a change from my local machine to my remote git repo.
2. A hook pulls the files into directory ABC.
3. guard notices the changes.
4. guard deletes the files in directory DEF.
5. guard uses jekyll to build the site to directory DEF.

I have everything set up except for #4. Does the guardfile allow for regular commands like `rm`? If not could I use guard-rake to call a rakefile that deleted the old content and then ran the Jekyll build?

Thanks.